# How to search for multiple column in mysql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, search

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ICT_Assigment_3
{
    public partial class search : Form
    {
        public search()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        DataTable dbdataset;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=password";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(" select BookName,Publisher,Category,Edition,Year,Location from library.add_update ;", conDataBase);
            try
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
                dbdataset = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

                bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
                sda.Update(dbdataset);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView DV = new DataView(dbdataset);
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("BookName LIKE '%{0}%'", search_box.Text);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;

        }
    }
}
```

I have done the search function, but it just can search my database by name, how to add another column, like publisher, i type the name it will also show the book same as category, location etc. Can anyone help me to improve this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use a parameterized query o build it dynamically:

```
private DataTable FilterRecords()
{
    bool where_set = false;

    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=password";

    string commandText = "select BookName, Publisher, Category, Edition, Year,"
                         + "Location from library.add_update "
                         + "where "

    // build your own filters
    //
    if (filter_by_name)
    {
        commandText += "name like '%" + varName + "%'";
        where_set = true;
    }

    if (filter_by_publisher)
    {
        if (where_set) commandText += " and ";
        commandText += "name like '%" + varName + "%'";
        where_set = true;
    }

    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        adp.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        adp.Fill(table);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Take a look, you must modify filters.

Add a function like that in you class and assign it to the bindigsource of the datagrid every time you want to filter some records. Use some variable to tell the function what you want to filter, or pass a filter as a function parameter and add it to the commandText;

```
DataGrid.DataSource = FilterRecords();
```

Comment: Sorry, how do i add this in? I'm new to everything in C#. I just started, can you show me?

Comment: Take a look a try to understand what the method do.

Comment: hey, I didn't realize it's a mysql, change my Sql.......... objects by MySql......